# Push object in array create another array

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var arr = this.products.find(x => x.id == 3);
```

I'm trying to push an object in this array like:

```
arr.push({ id: "5", name: "foo3" });
```

the problem is that I get an array which includes two arrays.

NB: this.products is defined in the prototype of the class and contains an array of objects

```
console.log(arr):

[Array(4)]
0: Array(4)
0: {id: "1", name: "test"}
1: {id: "2", name: "foo"}
2: {id: "3", name: "foo2"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: No, you don't, if your code sample is accurate. See @ThatBrianDude 's answer.

Comment: Your update makes even less sence unless `this.products` contains objects that have a push method.

Comment: Show a `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` output before doing `arr.push`. You don't expect `arr.push` to affect `this.products`, do you?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
   { id: "1", option: { bound_id: "2" }},
   { id: "2", option: { bound_id: "12" }},
   { id: "12", option: { bound_id: "2" }}
]
    
arr.push({ id: "5", option: { bound_id: "4" }})
    
console.log(arr)
```

Please make sure thats exactly how your code is written. If so it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `find` will return **the first element found** that satisfies the function that you pass as the [documentation says.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

second, there is no `push` function for an object.

as you can see in the snippet below, your code doesnt work, but we may have an idea of what you were trying.

```js
this.products = [{
    id: "1",
    option: {
      bound_id: "5"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    option: {
      bound_id: "8"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    option: {
      bound_id: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    option: {
      bound_id: "1"
    }
  }
]
var arr = this.products.find(x => x.id == 3);

console.log("this IS NOT AN ARRAY", arr)

//this isnt a function, it doesnt even work.
arr.push({
  id: "5",
  name: "foo3"
});
```

now lets try to see what you were trying to do:

1) complete new array containing both, previous array and the new option at the end.

2) array filterinr the ones with ID === 3

```js
let arr = [{
    id: "1",
    option: {
      bound_id: "5"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    option: {
      bound_id: "8"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    option: {
      bound_id: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    option: {
      bound_id: "1"
    }
  }
]

const otherObj = {
  id: "5",
  option: {
    bound_id: "4"
  }
}

//complete new array containing both, previous array and the new option at the end.
const newArray = [...arr, otherObj]

//array filterinr the ones with ID === 3
const newArrayFiltered = [...arr.filter(i => i.id !== "3"), otherObj]

console.log(newArray)
console.log(newArrayFiltered)
```